# INTERVAL near line 1 : Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, date, jpa

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
> unexpected token: INTERVAL near

Here is my query:

```
 private static final String USERS_NOT_ACTION_IN_LAST_MONTH = select u from myTable u where u.lastDate + INTERVAL 30 DAY <= CURDATE();

 @Override
 public List<MyEntity> getItemOlderThanMonth() {
    Query q = _entityManager.createQuery(USERS_NOT_ACTION_IN_LAST_MONTH, MyEntity.class);
    return q.getResultList();
 }
```

I want to get records older than 30 days.

Comment: ANSI SQL way: `INTERVAL '30' DAY`

Comment: In terms of performance `select u from myTable u where u.lastDate  <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL '30' DAY;` is more safe.

Comment: but getting same error : "unexpected token: INTERVAL"

Comment: hql has no INTERVAL syntax. MySQL has.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate current date by query parameter(current_date- 30)

```
private static final String USERS_NOT_ACTION_IN_LAST_MONTH = select u from myTable u where u.lastDate <= :calculated_date;
```

where calculated_date=current_date -30 days.

Answer (score 0):

By using _entityManager.createQuery hibernate sql (hql) script is created and hibernate doesn't have INTERVAL key word.

But createNativeQuery is native sql and behaves as normal sql script. So for mysql db INTERVAL key word should work. So smth like that

```
_entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from myTable u where u.lastDate + INTERVAL 30 DAY <= CURDATE()");
```

Answer (score 0):

@ARPAN CHAKARVARTY's answer helped me get to what I needed. Here is my Groovy code.

```
 final int DELETE_OLDER_THAN = 90

 Map restrictions = [date: new Date() - DELETE_OLDER_THAN]
        String query = """select a
                           from history a
                           where date <= :date
                        """
        List<History> histories = History.executeQuery(
                query, restrictions, [max: 100, offset: null])
```